# Can't delete git branch in the remote

Tags: git

I can't delete the branch in my remote server.
First I tried this one

> git push origin --delete devTime

but it gives me an error like this:

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

so while searching to fix this error I found this one and tried it

> git remote add origin devTime

and tried again this code

> git push origin --delete devTime

but this time it gives me an error like this:

> fatal: 'devTime' does not appear to be a git repository
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

by this time I got stock up.
Can some help me with this? Thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

`git push origin :devTime` should do the trick!

Comment: `git push origin --delete devTime` is equivalent to that command.  The OP is missing the origin remote.

Answer (score 0):

Run 
`git remote -v` to see what your git repository's origin contains and then point it to the right repository by running `git remote add origin <remote_git_repo's url>`

Comment: Hi i tried this, but I'm quite confuse,it gives me this: 
origin devTime (fetch)
origin devTime (push)

and don't know what is the difference between these two.

Answer (score 0):

Your repository did not have a remote repository named origin.  Perhaps it never had one.  Perhaps it got deleted.  Are you sure you're in the right directory?

A remote repository is a named url, which is why trying to add a remove called "devTime" did not work, that is a branch name.

To fix this, you need to remove your broken remote and add a new one.

- `git remote rm origin` (to remove the bogus "devTime" remote you added)
- `git remote add origin <remote repository URL>`
- `git push origin --delete devTime`

Comment: @akbsmile, you did `git remote add origin devTime` thus messed up your repository configuration, the command here are needed to fix your configured repository, i.e. what `origin` points to.